# Accessing an object created in another class

Tags: java, object

I create a thread in my main class. 
The thread has a timer which writes and reads on a socket.

I need to call a method in the thread class e.g writeSomething()  from another class outside of where it was declared(Main).

How is the object referenced from another class?

**Edit**

```
public static Thread connectionThread;

ModelJTable table = new ModelJTable();
connectionThread = new Thread(new ConnectionThread(table), "connectionThread");
connectionThread.start();
```

I have a method in the thread class

```
public void openFile(String fileName){
    String request = "open;" + fileName;
    out.print(request);
}
```

I want to access if from another class(the JTable class)

```
String open = "open;" + getname + ";" + getpath;
// This doesnt work 
ConnectionThread.openFile(open);
```

This call gives an error

> No enclosing instance of the type ConnectionThread is accessible in 
>    scope

Comment: Do you just need to call the method or do you need to call the method of that specific instance of the class?

Comment: Well, I have a thread which has a socket connection, and a bufferedreader and printwriter to the stream. I basically just need to make the thread write a message to the socket. The message I create somewhere else and want to call the thread method from this class.If I just call the method, and the method writes to the created printwriter, will a call be sufficient(not to a specific object)

Comment: have you try implementing my answer?

Comment: @org.life.java: Yeah, I tried the static way and cant access the methods on the static object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either pass it in constructor of second class OR make it static in first class, OR serialize it

way 1: static one

```
Class A{
public static int a=0;
}

Class B{
public void someMethod(){
A.a = 10;
}
}
```

Comment: or use a accessor (getter) method

Comment: @alJaree Check update, and next time when you comment please make sure you write @org.life.java with no space after @

Comment: I redid the comment. Is that for search functionality?

Comment: Yes , it will notify the person on discussion

Comment: @org.life.java I updated my question, please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to access `openFile` from anywhere just make it public static , you will be accessing it wuthout creating instance of the class enclosing method. just like `public static void open(String file){}`

Comment: @org.life.java I have the PrintWriter called out which then needs to be static too. Wont this static domino effect cause issues?

Comment: Please read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) once

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference to the Thread to the class that needs to call the method.

Comment: If I create the thread in main. Thread connectionThread = new blah blah, should I just have the following in the calling class Thread connectionThread; ? or what do u mean by pass?

Comment: Pass a reference to the connectionThread to the calling class.

Comment: The thread is passed the calling class before that. Are there any other ways?